# Detecting 12bit images in 16bit

Tags: gdal, digital-image-processing, bit-depth

**Setting**

For the purpose of a machine learning algorithm I'm tying to automatically scale images of arbitrary bitdepth to unit interval, i.e. I want to map pixels from [0,2<sup>x</sup>] to [0,1] simply by dividing all pixels by 2<sup>x</sup>. I want to do this without knowing anything about the pixelvalue distribution or statistics inside the image. The only thing that I know is the metadata. To open images I use `gdal` in python via

```
data = gdal.Open(path)
```

The images are given in `.tif` or `.img` format.

**Problem**

Typically 12bit images will be saved in a 16bit format, where pixel values above 4095 won't occure. Nevertheless the meta tag bitdepth will be 16bit.

**Question**

Is there any valid way to check whether an image is a true 16bit image or a 12bit image inside a 16bit image, without calculating the statistics? Is there any meta tag that serves this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a meta tag but it isn't in the default domain:

```
data = gdal.Open(path)
band = data.GetRasterBand(1) 
band.GetMetadata('IMAGE_STRUCTURE')
# {'NBITS': '12'}
```

For the full list of metadata domains use

```
band.GetMetadataDomainList()
# ['IMAGE_STRUCTURE', '']
```

Answer (score 1):

At least when the GeoTIFF image is created with GDAL you can check the NBITS value with gdalinfo.

Create a test image

```
gdal_translate -of gtiff -ot uint16 -co nbits=12 base.tif base12.tif
```

Have a look at the metadata

```
gdalinfo base12.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: base12.tif
Size is 10000, 10000
Coordinate System is `'
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,10000.0)
Upper Right (10000.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (10000.0,10000.0)
Center      ( 5000.0, 5000.0)
Band 1 Block=10000x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Red
  Image Structure Metadata:
    NBITS=12
Band 2 Block=10000x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Green
  Image Structure Metadata:
    NBITS=12
Band 3 Block=10000x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Blue
  Image Structure Metadata:
    NBITS=12
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  Unfortunately I don't have the control about the data creation, but I see your point. Somehow the information needs to be added manually somewhere to the meta tags i.e. the workflow of early data processing needs to be adapted.